# LINQ var .tolist() as datasource for repeater, what to put as field name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

im using the below to bind a list to a repeater

```
var confhullresults = (from b in dtConf.AsEnumerable()
                       where b.Field<string>("Location") == "Hull"
                       select b).ToList();

rptConfHull.DataSource = confhullresults;
rptConfHull.DataBind();
```

then in the aspx page where i normally have

```
<%# Eval("FieldName") #>
```

I dont know what to put, i can see in the last that all the fields are name 0,1,2,3 but ive tried

```
<%# Eval(0) #>
```

and

```
<%# Eval("0") #>
```

no luck, anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: <%# ((DataRow)DataItem)["FieldName"] #> maybe

Comment: How does your array - dtConf - look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var confhullresults = (from b in dtConf.AsEnumerable()
                       where b.Field<string>("Location") == "Hull"
                       select new{ Location= b.Field<string>("Location")}).ToList();
```

and bind

```
<%# Eval("Location") #>
```